# ¿Porque mi página web me dice que tengo mal la respuesta y me la corrige por la respuesta de la nueva operación?

Tags: javascript, html, script, ordenamiento

Hola Buenas tardes a todos, en mi escuela me pidieron que hiciera una página web con JavaScript que le preguntara al usuario el número faltante, por ejemplo: 6 + ? = 10, que número debe de estar en la incógnita para que de el resultado mostrado.Siguiendo las siguentes Reglas:

La computadora selecciona al azar una operación (+, -, *, /). Nota: Todas las operaciones se manejan en formato entero (para evitar las decimales en la división).

La computadora selecciona al azar dos cantidades en un rango (establecido por el  programador, puede ser 10, 15, 20, etc.).

El usuario escribe su respuesta y con un botón la confirma.
La computadora lleva y muestra un conteo de los aciertos y fallos del usuario.
Botón de reinicio del juego.

[image: Esta es la foto de la página cuando me pide el número faltante]
[image: Esta es la foto de cuando ya ingresé el dato y me marca que estoy mal]

Comparto mi código de HTML integrado con JS

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <title> Juego de operaciones </title>
  <script lenguaje="JavaScript">
   var resUsuario, res, res1, incognita, numeroCom, operación, victorias=0, perdidos=0;

 function Juego(){
  operación = parseInt(4 * Math.random(),10);
  incognita = parseInt(10 * Math.random(),10);
  numeroCom = parseInt(10 * Math.random(),10);
        
         if(operación == 0){
  res =  numeroCom + incognita; 
  document.datos.txtRes.value = "" + numeroCom + " + " + "?" + " = " + res;
  }
  else if(operación == 1){
                 res =  numeroCom - incognita; 
          document.datos.txtRes.value = "" + numeroCom + " - " + "?" + " = " + res;
  }
  else if(operación == 2){
                 res =  numeroCom * incognita;
                 document.datos.txtRes.value = "" + numeroCom + " * " + "?" + " = " + res;
         }
  else if(operación == 3){
                 res1 =  numeroCom / incognita;
   res = Math.round(res1);
                 document.datos.txtRes.value = "" + numeroCom + " * " + "?" + " = " + res;
         }
         }

            function Resolver(){
  if(incognita == resUsuario){
                 document.datos.txtResUsua.value= "Correcto";
                 victorias++;
                }else{
                    document.datos.txtResUsua1.value = "Incorrecto, la respuesta correcta es: " + incognita;
                    perdidos++;
                    }
            document.datos.txtVan.value = "Victorias: " + victorias + " Derrotas " + perdidos;
            resUsuario = parseInt(document.datos.txtUsuario);
            }

     function Reiniciar()
     {
      ganados=0;
      perdidos=0; 
      document.datos.txtResUsua1.value = "";
      document.datos.txtVan.value = ""; 
     }

    </script>
   </head>
   <body>
   <hr> <h1 style="text-align:center;"> Juego de Operaciones!!! </h1> <hr>

   <form name=datos>
   <input type=button name=btnJugar value="Jugar" onClick="Juego();"> <br> <br>
   ¿Qué número falta? <br>
   <input type=text name=txtRes disabled>
     Contestar: <input type=text name=txtUsuario"> <br> <br>
     <input type=button name=btnAceptar value="Aceptar" onClick="Juego(); Resolver();"> <br> <br>
     Respuesta: <input type=text name=txtResUsua1 disabled size=100px> <br> <br>
     Conteo: <input type=text name=txtVan disabled size=50px> <br> <br> 
     Reiniciar: <input type=button name=btnBorrar value="Borrar" onClick="Reiniciar();"> <br> <br>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Como consejo en la implementación, no uses `else` y luego dentro uses un `if` si no directamente haz `else if` para cumplir los estándares y que tu código sea más legible.

Comment: Siento mucho que no sea tan legible mi código, muchas gracias

Comment: Recientemente lo modifiqué, muchas gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero ordené un poco el código porque era un poco difícil de leer (como bien ya te dijeron).

Yendo a tu consulta, tenías 2 problemas concretos:

- El botón de "Aceptar" ejecutaba primero la función `Juego()` y después `Resolver()`, con lo cual evaluaba el valor que habías ingresado pero lo hacía contra la nueva pregunta. Cambié el orden.
- Por otro lado, en la función `Resolver()` los primero que haces es comparar `incognita` con `resUsuario`, pero nunca le asignaste un valor a `resUsuario`, lo hacés al final de la función, así que eso lo moví al principio. Así mismo, le estabas asignando mal el valor, te faltaba el `.value` al final.

Por como lo tenés armado algunas ecuaciones no se puede resolver, por ejemplo:

`9 * ? = 1`

```js
var resUsuario, res, res1, incognita, numeroCom, operación, victorias = 0,
  perdidos = 0;

function Juego() {
  operación = parseInt(4 * Math.random(), 10);
  incognita = parseInt(10 * Math.random(), 10);
  numeroCom = parseInt(10 * Math.random(), 10);

  if (operación == 0) {
    res = numeroCom + incognita;
    document.datos.txtRes.value = "" + numeroCom + " + " + "?" + " = " + res;
  } else if (operación == 1) {
    res = numeroCom - incognita;
    document.datos.txtRes.value = "" + numeroCom + " - " + "?" + " = " + res;
  } else if (operación == 2) {
    res = numeroCom * incognita;
    document.datos.txtRes.value = "" + numeroCom + " * " + "?" + " = " + res;
  } else if (operación == 3) {
    res1 = numeroCom / incognita;
    res = Math.round(res1);
    document.datos.txtRes.value = "" + numeroCom + " * " + "?" + " = " + res;
  }
}

function Resolver() {
  resUsuario = parseInt(document.datos.txtUsuario.value);

  if (incognita == resUsuario) {
    document.datos.txtResUsua1.value = "Correcto";
    victorias++;
  } else {
    document.datos.txtResUsua1.value = "Incorrecto, la respuesta correcta es: " + incognita;
    perdidos++;
  }

  document.datos.txtVan.value = "Victorias: " + victorias + " Derrotas " + perdidos;
}

function Reiniciar() {
  ganados = 0;
  perdidos = 0;
  document.datos.txtResUsua1.value = "";
  document.datos.txtVan.value = "";
}
```

```html
<hr>
<h1 style="text-align:center;"> Juego de Operaciones!!! </h1>
<hr>

<form name="datos">
  <input type="button" name="btnJugar" value="Jugar" onClick="Juego();">
  <br>
  <br>
  ¿Qué número falta?
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="txtRes" disabled> Contestar: <input type="text" name="txtUsuario">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" name="btnAceptar" value="Aceptar" onClick="Resolver();Juego();">
  <br>
  <br>
  Respuesta: <input type="text" name="txtResUsua1" disabled size="100px">
  <br>
  <br>
  Conteo: <input type="text" name="txtVan" disabled size="50px">
  <br>
  <br>
  Reiniciar: <input type="button" name="btnBorrar" value="Borrar" onClick="Reiniciar();">
</form>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por ayudarme a entender los problemas y una disculpa por hacer que código se poco legible no sabía que era válido poner "else if" directo, soy nuevo con esto de la programación web.